# I'm getting referenced before assignment

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm finding an error I can't seem to fix since I added an update the other day the error is local variable is referenced before assignment I'm not sure what the issue is here? can anyone help?

```
line 243, in on_reaction_add
if has_message is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'has_message' referenced before assignment
```

Code

```
 async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        server = reaction.message.server
        msg = reaction.message
        if server.id not in self.settings:
            return
        if msg.channel.id in self.settings[server.id]["ignore"]:
            return
        if not await self.check_roles(user, msg.author, server):
            return
        react =self.settings[server.id]["emoji"]
        if react in str(reaction.emoji):
            threshold = self.settings[server.id]["threshold"]
            count = await self.get_count(server, msg)
            if await self.check_is_posted(server, msg):
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.settings[server.id]["channel"])
                msg_id, count = await self.get_posted_message(server, msg)
                if msg_id is not None:
                    msg_edit = await self.bot.get_message(channel, msg_id)
                    await self.bot.edit_message(msg_edit, new_content="{} **#{}**".format(reaction.emoji, count-1))
                    return
            if count < threshold and threshold != 0:
                store = {"original_message":msg.id, "new_message":None,"count":count+1}
                for message in self.settings[server.id]["messages"]:
                    has_message = None
                    if msg.id == message["original_message"]:
                        has_message = message
                if has_message is not None:
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].remove(has_message)
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].append(store)
                    dataIO.save_json("data/star/settings.json", self.settings)
                else:
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].append(store)
                    dataIO.save_json("data/star/settings.json", self.settings)
                return
            if threshold == 0:
                count = 2
            # else:
```

Which would be this line of code:

```
if has_message is not None:
    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].remove(has_message)
    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].append(store)
    dataIO.save_json("data/star/settings.json", self.settings)
```

Comment: You declare that variable in a loop. That means if there is no loop iteration, it is not defined. Ergo, `self.settings[server.id]["messages"]` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you didn't initialize the variable `has_message` in memory.
Just add it like so.

```
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        has_message = None
        server = reaction.message.server
        msg = reaction.message
        if server.id not in self.settings:
            return
        if msg.channel.id in self.settings[server.id]["ignore"]:
            return
        if not await self.check_roles(user, msg.author, server):
            return
        react =self.settings[server.id]["emoji"]
        if react in str(reaction.emoji):
            threshold = self.settings[server.id]["threshold"]
            count = await self.get_count(server, msg)
            if await self.check_is_posted(server, msg):
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.settings[server.id]["channel"])
                msg_id, count = await self.get_posted_message(server, msg)
                if msg_id is not None:
                    msg_edit = await self.bot.get_message(channel, msg_id)
                    await self.bot.edit_message(msg_edit, new_content="{} **#{}**".format(reaction.emoji, count-1))
                    return
            if count < threshold and threshold != 0:
                store = {"original_message":msg.id, "new_message":None,"count":count+1}
                for message in self.settings[server.id]["messages"]:
                    has_message = None
                    if msg.id == message["original_message"]:
                        has_message = message
                if has_message is not None:
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].remove(has_message)
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].append(store)
                    dataIO.save_json("data/star/settings.json", self.settings)
                else:
                    self.settings[server.id]["messages"].append(store)
                    dataIO.save_json("data/star/settings.json", self.settings)
                return
            if threshold == 0:
                count = 2
            # else:
```

Comment: Pls remove all the completely irrelevant spaghetti parts.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't mean all the rest is relevant to the question. At least explain why it is undefined when the OP tries to access it. And fix the uneven indentation.